# p5.js - change trail of shapes being drawn

Tags: draw, p5.js

In my program, running your mouse over the screen will leave a trail of black, semi-transparent circles. I want to be able to change that by pressing the 'i' key, at which point it should draw a trailing blue line. Currently, upon pressing the 'i' key, it does draw a trailing blue line, but that line is surrounded by black, semi-transparent circles. If I try to call background, it solves the circle problem, but makes the line's trail disappear shortly after being drawn.

```
    if (mouseY < 417) { //canvas is 500x500
      noStroke();
      fill(0,100);
      ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,20,20);
   } 

   if (keyIsPressed && key == 'i') {
     if (mouseY < 417) {
       stroke(0,0,255);
       line(mouseX,mouseY,pmouseX,pmouseY);
     }
   }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one thing OR another thing to happen, but not both, you need to use an `if` statement *and* an `else` statement.

```
if (condition) {
    // this stuff happens if condition is true...
} else {
    // ...otherwise this other stuff happens
}
```